# Javascript Check if a Value for a given Key exists in array of Dictionaries

Tags: javascript

For a given string, how do I check if it exists for a given key in an array of dictionaries?

For example, I would like to check if the value "ww" exists for a "Key1", for all the objects contained in my arrayOfDictionaries[] that has the following values:

```
obj1 = [{"key1": "aa", {"key2": "bb"}, {"key3": "cc"}];
obj2 = [{"key1": "dd", {"key2": "ee"}, {"key3": "ff"}];
...
objN = [{"key1": "ww", {"key2": "yy"}, {"key3": "zz"}];
```

Comment: let me see if i get your thing. You have arrayOfDictionaries = [.[{key1:'aa',], [{'key2','bb'}] ,...   ] and wants to to know IF there is AT LEAST ONE value X on AT LEAST ONE dictionary?

Comment: Yes, AT LEAST ONE value X, FOR A GIVEN KEY on AT LEAST ONE dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check if there is **ONE value for ONE key at least once in at least ONE dictionary**

### Option 1

You need to iterate in two levels using Array.find

Draw back is that it will only stop to iterate when it finds the item so if your item is, lets say at the end of the last dictionary you'll iterate through it all.

```
let arrayOfDictionaries = [
    [{ key1: "AAA1", key2: "AAA1", key3: "AAA1", key4: "AAA1" }],
    [{ key1: "AAA2", key2: "AAA2", key3: "AAA2", key4: "AAA2" }],
    [{ key1: "AAA3", key2: "AAA3", key3: "AAA3", key4: "AAA3" }],
    [{ key1: "AAA4", key2: "AAA4", key3: "AAA4", key4: "AAA4" }],
];

const hasKeyValue = (array, key, value) => {
    let found = false;
    array.find((dict) => {
        if (found) return dict;
        dict.find((obj) => {
            if (obj[key] == value) {
                found = true;
                return obj;
            }
        });
    });
    return found;
};

console.log( hasKeyValue(arrayOfDictionaries,'key1', 'AAA1')?'YES':'NO'); //YES
console.log( hasKeyValue(arrayOfDictionaries,'key1', 'AAA2')?'YES':'NO'); //YES
console.log( hasKeyValue(arrayOfDictionaries,'key1', 'AAA3')?'YES':'NO'); //YES
console.log( hasKeyValue(arrayOfDictionaries,'key1', 'AAA4')?'YES':'NO'); //YES
console.log( hasKeyValue(arrayOfDictionaries,'key1', 'AAA5')?'YES':'NO'); //NO
console.log( hasKeyValue(arrayOfDictionaries,'key1', 'AA1')?'YES':'NO'); //NO
console.log( hasKeyValue(arrayOfDictionaries,'key1', 'AA2')?'YES':'NO'); //NO
```

### Option 2

You transform you arrayOfDictionaries into a JSON string and check for your key:value

Drawback is that depending on the size of your arrayOfDictionaries machine will take some time to stringify

```
let arrayOfDictionaries = [
    [{ key1: "AAA1", key2: "AAA1", key3: "AAA1", key4: "AAA1" }],
    [{ key1: "AAA2", key2: "AAA2", key3: "AAA2", key4: "AAA2" }],
    [{ key1: "AAA3", key2: "AAA3", key3: "AAA3", key4: "AAA3" }],
    [{ key1: "AAA4", key2: "AAA4", key3: "AAA4", key4: "AAA4" }],
];


let JSONString = JSON.stringify(arrayOfDictionaries);

let hasKeyValue2 = (json,key,value)=>{
    return json.indexOf('"'+key+'":"'+value+'"')>-1;
}
console.log( hasKeyValue2(JSONString,'key1', 'AAA1')?'YES':'NO'); //YES
console.log( hasKeyValue2(JSONString,'key1', 'AAA2')?'YES':'NO'); //YES
console.log( hasKeyValue2(JSONString,'key1', 'AAA3')?'YES':'NO'); //YES
console.log( hasKeyValue2(JSONString,'key1', 'AAA4')?'YES':'NO'); //YES
console.log( hasKeyValue2(JSONString,'key1', 'AAA5')?'YES':'NO'); //NO
console.log( hasKeyValue2(JSONString,'key1', 'AA1')?'YES':'NO'); //NO
console.log( hasKeyValue2(JSONString,'key1', 'AA2')?'YES':'NO'); //NO
```

Comment: For my purpose, Option 2 is better and works great. Thank you!

Comment: Nice. To go further than this, we would have to discuss what exactly youre trying to achieve. Creating Indexes, and things like things